# Accessing an object's parent

Tags: javascript

Ok, first up I know an object has no reference to it's container unless explicitly defined, so I am looking for a work around here.

Take the following code (heavily simplified from my use case for readability):

```
var cid = 0;
var Command = function(c) {
    this.id = cid += 1;
    this.transient = false;
    return this;
}

var sid = 0;
var CommandSet = function() {
    this.id = sid += 1;
    this.commands = [];
    this.transients = 0;
    return this;
}

CommandSet.prototype.parent = null;
CommandSet.prototype.recurse = function(callback) {
    callback.call(this);
    if (this.parent instanceof CommandSet) {
        this.parent.recurse(callback);
    }
}

CommandSet.prototype.createSubset = function() {
    var set = new CommandSet();
    set.parent = this;
    set.commands = this.commands;
    set.transients = this.transients;
    return set;
}


CommandSet.prototype.addCommand = function(c) {
    if (c instanceof Command) {
        this.commands.push(c);
        if (c.transient) {
            this.recurse(function() {
                this.transients++;
            });
        }
    }
    return this;
}

CommandSet.prototype.toggleTransient = function(c) {
    if (c instanceof Command) {
        c.transient = true;
        this.recurse(function() {
            this.transients++;
        });
    }
    return this;
}
```

If I then do the following (http://jsfiddle.net/5KGd8/1/):

```
var s1 = new CommandSet();
var c1 = new Command();
var c2 = new Command();
s1.addCommand(c1).addCommand(c2);

var s2 = s1.createSubset();
var s3 = s1.createSubset();
s2.toggleTransient(c1);

console.log(s1);
console.log(s2);
console.log(s3);
```

`s1` now has 1 transient, `s2` now has 1 transient but `s3` still has none despite containing a reference to the same `Command` objects.

**Possible solutions:**

1. I could build a reference into each command which stores all the
   sets it is located inside and iterate through those, however this is
   going to cause some serious memory issues as the real nature of my
   application requires that subsets can be garbage collected (The user
   will create a lot of them anonymously often without realising) and this will retain a
   reference to them after they have been used. The `parent` reference is fine as I want the parent set to exist as long as it has a surviving subset.
2. I could explicitly force the user to run a delete function on a
   subset when it is no longer needed which would remove all internal references to it but this complicates things for
   them and I like things to work automagically. The nature of my application means I would like the user to create subsets at times where they may not even realise they have done so (Through other functions which create and perform on subsets).

Can anyone think of a way to solve this problem without the issues described in my two solutions?

Comment: Why are you `return this`ing from the functions called as constructors?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum no reason... no reason at all.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify - you'd like to figure out the number of transients of a command (not sure what that means) based on all the supersets it's a member of?

Comment: `commands` is an array and you are only copying the reference to it but `transients` is a number which is really copied

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What a transient is doesn't matter, it could be bananas .etc, it is just a boolean on the `Command` object. I want all sets that contain `Command` objects to have an up to date count of how many `Command` objects it contains with a transient value of true.

Comment: @jantimon Transients are copied because it is faster here, in my use case I calculate it but here it is impossible to create a subset with a differing number of transient `Command` objects. I don't want to pass it by reference as a subset can contain a different number of transients than it's parent in my use case (Contain only some of the commands it's parent contains). `Command` objects are passed by reference on purpose.

Comment: Can you use Object.defineProperty with the second parameter to turn transient into a pair of getter and setter functions? You can leave out the setter but a getter would always return the right amount as it's iterates through `this.commands`. If you can't then maybe turn transient into a function that returns transient commands (not sure if that will greatly affect performance)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not an answer but want to make sure I understand the problem.

A CommandSet can have Commands, when you change a Command's transient property you would like the CommandSet(s) that contain that Command to have an updated counter of transient the Commands it contains.

If the story ends here you could simply have Command maintain a list of CommandSet that the Command is in and update it's containers.

This would not work however because you would have CommandSets created in a function and when these go out of scope they won't be garbage collected because the Command(s) they contain would hold a reference to them. These commands would not go out of scope with the CommandSets because they are also contained in other (global) CommandSets.

Re assigning a primitive type (transients) does not re assign that in the subset or main set, but what if transients was not a primitive?

In the constructor:

```
this.transients = {count:0};
```

In createSubset

```
set.transients = this.transients
```

In the toggleTransient

```
this.transients.count++; or --
```

No matter if you fiddle with transients in subset or main set, as long as you use the toggleTransient it'll change `count` for all.

Comment: Thanks, you have a good grip of the problem. Although I oversimplified my problem in the question and forgot to mention that a subset could have a different number of transients to it's parent set (In my actual use case subsets normally contain only some of their parent's commands). The problem with passing the transient count via reference to the subsets is they will always have the  same transient count as the parent and vice versa.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Is there a time limit on the validity of the CommandSets? Like when they're not used within a certain amount of time you could safely say they're expired and references to/from their commands could be cleaned up?

Comment: I'm afraid not. It is totally up to the user as to when the `CommandSet`s are no longer relevant by allowing them to drop out of scope. Note the user in this case is another programmer; this is part of a library I am building.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Even if you create one object that uses CommandSet id's and Command id's to update certain totals in CommandSets These states will be uselessly retained when a CommandSet goes out of scope. Since an object is not notified when it's going to garbage collected you can't tell the "CommandSetState" object to delete the details for that CommandSet. You'll leak less but it's still leaking. I'm curious if anyone finds a way out of this one.

Comment: Indeed, if only JavaScript had weak referencing - that would solve all my issues. I've never looked into it but I assume event listeners create strong references, otherwise it may be possible to register event listeners from sets to their commands. Although not a working answer up-voted for helpfulness.

Comment: @GeorgeReith for events to work they have to know the instance to invoke the listener method on, usually done through closures. That's why I asked if they would expire. The closure can de-reference the particular CommandSet instance when an expiry time has passed.